# cake php ajax refresh two elements in separate divs

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have view books/browse which uses 3 elements (those elements don't use any requestAction, they just depend on variables set in books/browse controller. Each element is enclosed in separate div with id of this element. Now I want to have a link which will refresh with ajax 2 of 3 elements. For now I have something like this (this is in books/browse view):

```
echo $this->Js->link('Page 2', array('page' => 2), array('update' => '#element_id'));
```

and in books/browse controller I have:

```
 ...
            $this->set('books', $books);    
            $this->set('author_keywords',$author_keywords);
            $this->set('title_keywords',$title_keywords);
            $this->set('languages',$languages);
            $this->set('language_id',$language_id);
            $this->set('limit',$limit); 
            $this->set('category_id',$category_id);

            if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) 
            {
                 $this->autoRender = false;
                 $this->layout = 'ajax';
                 $this->render('/elements/element1');
            }
            return;
```

And this works fine, the element in div 'element_id' is refreshed with proper contents of elements/element1

Now I want to update 2 element in separate divs in a single request. So maybe is there option to pass to link 2 divs which should be updated - but how then use the controller to render two elements in those 2 divs?

--edit

the purpose of this is to ommit refreshing one element on the page as its database queries and rendering are slow, and it doesnt change...

-- edit

Okay I have an idea on how to do it - in controller I have to render two elements and save html returned by those elements in two variables, then return ajax data like some array with 2 variables containing those elements html. Then I have to use JS to update two divs... But how to do it in controller?

Comment: If you want the controller to know what element to render, couldn't you just pass the element name to it via passed args or the query string?

Comment: Ofc I can but I need to render two elements to update two divs and I dont know how to render and buffer them in an array/variables and return as a ajax response